# Build Bazel package from multiple repos

Tags: opencv, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to build OpenCV with external modules, but haven't been able to come up with a clean solution.

I have successfully built OpenCV using CMake (rules_foreign_cc). But to be able to build with external modules I need to download a separate repo (opencv_contrib) and then build using the path to the second repo as a build argument.

Is there a way I can do this without having to create a git repo of my own that combines these two git repos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# WORKSPACE file

http_archive(
   name = "rules_foreign_cc",
   strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-4010620160e0df4d894b61496d3d3b6fc8323212",
    sha256 = "07e3414cc841b1f4d16e5231eb818e5c5e03e2045827f5306a55709e5045c7fd",
   url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/4010620160e0df4d894b61496d3d3b6fc8323212.zip",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:repositories.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")
rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()


http_archive(
    name = "opencv_contrib",
    build_file="//:opencv_contrib.BUILD",
    sha256 = "9f52fd3114ac464cb4c9a2a6a485c729a223afb57b9c24848484e55cef0b5c2a",
    urls = ["https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/refs/tags/4.5.2.tar.gz"],
    strip_prefix = "opencv_contrib-4.5.2",
)

http_archive(
    name = "opencv",
    sha256="ae258ed50aa039279c3d36afdea5c6ecf762515836b27871a8957c610d0424f8",
    build_file="//:opencv.BUILD",
    urls = ["https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/refs/tags/4.5.2.tar.gz"],
    strip_prefix = "opencv-4.5.2",
)
```

```py
# opencv_contrib.BUILD file

filegroup(
    name = "modules",
    srcs = glob(["modules/**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

```py
# opencv.BUILD file

load("@rules_foreign_cc//foreign_cc:defs.bzl", "cmake")

filegroup(
    name = "srcs",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
cmake(
    name = "opencv",
    generate_args = ["-GNinja"],
    additional_inputs=["@opencv_contrib//:modules"],
    cache_entries = {
        "BUILD_SHARED_LIBS": "OFF",
        "BUILD_opencv_world": "ON",
        "OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH": "$$EXT_BUILD_ROOT$$/external/opencv_contrib/modules",
    },
    lib_source = ":srcs",
    out_static_libs = ["libopencv_world.a"],
)
```

Comment: What environment are you running this in? I get this error "OpenCV requires enabled 'cudev' module from 'opencv_contrib'" when I use Bazel 4.0 on Ubuntu 18.04. Thanks for the response!

Comment: the key here is `OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH`, to be explicit. opencv has documentation on that cmake variable.

Comment: Hi @Slay, when I do this the header files of opencv end-up in bazel-out/k8-dastbuild/bin/external/...
How can I get cmake to put the headers in external/ ?
Thanks...

Comment: Why do you want to have them there? Usually It does not make any sense, and it is more true in case of bazel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git_repository`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/repo/git.html) rule in your `WORKSPACE` file to have bazel automatically clone a git repo before building.

Once you add it to the `WORKSPACE` file, then you can reference build targets of the remote repo inside your own repo.

Check [this repo](https://github.com/ourarash/cpp-template) for an example.

Comment: I'm aware of the git_repository rule. My problem is not cloning the repos, but specifying the path to the other repo. For example, to build the first repo I need to pass in a build flag like this "-DEXTRA_MODULES=../opencv_contrib"